# R htmltools browsable HTML does not view without explicit print()

Tags: html, r

I can create HTML code in R that is wrapped with attributes using `htmltools` package functions.  This allows html to be rendered from the console (a browser window is automatically launched) as well as in R Markdown and Quarto documents.  But I can't get this to work without an explicit `print()`.  How to make it work with an implicit `print`?  Here is a minimal working example.

```
require(htmltools)

x <- readLines(textConnection('
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>'))

print.ctest <- function(x) browsable(HTML(x))

class(x) <- 'ctest'

print(x)   # opens browser
x          # does nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

If an object is called by its name it uses the default print method for the respective class. Convert x to HTML and call x afterwards it will implicit call print and launch the correct device ( browser)

```
require(htmltools)

x <- readLines(textConnection('
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>'))



class(x) # [1] "character"
x # prints character in console

x_1 <- browsable(HTML(x))
class(x_1) # [1] "html"      "character"
x_1 # shows HTML in browser without explicit print
```

Edit, to get the implicit print call to work with our custom class use `registerS3method` to link the method to the class

```
## change class
class(x) <- 'ctest'
## register its method
registerS3method("print", "ctest",function(x) {print(browsable(HTML(x)))} )

# now the class is recognized and our registered Method is used.
x
```

Comment: That is useful for top-level code.  But I need to have a  `print` method.  My real `print` method senses a user option to decide whether to render in plain text, $\latex$, or html.  I was hoping that if `print` resulted in `browsable(HTML(...))` with its classes and attributes that rendering would be automatic.

Comment: ok i understand , i will edit my answer i think iknow what you are looking for

Comment: You gave me the idea of enclosing the result of the `print.ctest` function in `print()`.  That did the trick.  I didn't need to run `registerS3method`.  I thought that if the user explicitly did `print(x)` that the resulting `print(print(x))` would cause a problem but I don't think it does.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon.  When I run the test in `Quarto` I'm getting the html in a pop-up browser window and not in the `Quarto` document.

Comment: you should be able to directly write html into the quarto ?

Comment: Yes, but to avoid having to remember putting `{r results='asis'}` in the chunk header you need to mark the html using `htmltools::HTML(generated html character strings)`.

Comment: The following seems to work in the `Quarto` context and also in the console.  I'm just getting some extraneous `yaml` created  when the constructed HTML contains `<style>, <div>, <span>`.:  ```rendHTML <- function(x) {
  x <- paste(x, collapse='\n')
  if(length(getOption('knitr.in.progress'))) 
    return(knitr::asis_output(x)) 
  print(htmltools::browsable(htmltools::HTML(x)))
}
```

Comment: Per help I received on the `Quarto` site, I enclosed the html with `{=html}` with three backticks at the end, which tells Pandoc to not malign the html.  All is well.  This is now in the `rendHTML` function in the new version of the `Hmisc` package that is currently being propaged across CRAN repos.